# Matlab simple loop not plotting correctly

Tags: matlab, loops, if-statement, for-loop, plot

I'm a Matlab newbie and I'm trying to figure out why my simple loop just won't plot like it should do.

Updated Code (moved from comment below 8/25)

```
rent_1=1400;
rent_2=1560;
b = zeros(1,10);
month_count = 1:10

y = month_count * rent_1;

for i = 1:10 
   if i == 1 | i == 2 | i == 3 
      b(1,i)=rent_2 * (i-0.5040); 
   elseif i == 4 
      b(1,i)=rent_2*(i-0.6300);
   elseif i == 5 
      b(1,i)=rent_2*(i-0.7565); 
   elseif i == 6 
      b(1,i)=rent_2*(i-0.8825); 
   elseif i == 7 
      b(1,i)=rent_2*(i-1.0085); 
   elseif i == 8 
      b(1,i)=rent_2*(i-1.1345); 
   else 
      b(1,i)=rent_2*(i-1.2605); 
   end 
end 

figure,
plot(month_count,y,i,b(1,i))
```

Original code (Posted 8/24):

```
rent_1=1400;
rent_2=1560;
b = zeros(1,10);
month_count = 1:10

y = month_count * rent_1;

if i=1:3
    for 1:3,
        b(1,i)=rent_2(i-0.5040);
    end
elseif i == 4
    b(1,i)=rent_2(i-0.6300);
elseif i == 5
    b(1,i)=rent_2(i-0.7565);
elseif i == 6
    b(1,i)=rent_2(i-0.8825);
elseif i == 7
    b(1,i)=rent_2(i-1.0085);
elseif i == 8
    b(1,i)=rent_2(i-1.1345);
else
    b(1,i)=rent_2(i-1.2605);
end

figure,
plot(month_count,y,i,b(1,i))
```

Would very much appreciate your feedback. Max Keiser.

Comment: can you briefly explain your code? you have several error going on and it is impossible to fix if we do not know what you are trying to achieve. For example, what is i? is it month_count? what do you mean by rent_2(i - 0.6300), does it mean you want to take 63% of the value of rent_2 at month i?

Comment: I suggest you *carefully* manually step through your code - that is, think about what's happening at each line. e.g. what does `if i = 1:3` do, what would `rent_2(i-0.5040)` return? Check at the command line with a simple example to make sure what you think is happening *is* happening. (Also read through http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html )

Comment: Try reorganizing your question and adding more details.  I'm also relatively new but I've found the best format for a question is a short description of what you are trying to do, the relevant part of the code, what it should be doing, and what it is doing that is not what you want.  Also if it is close to other questions on this site, link to them and explain what is different about your question. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your feedback. Basically, the code is trying to evaluate: (1)  the cumulative amount of rent received: y = month_count * rent_1; The other part (rent_2(i - 0.6300)) evaluated that after a certain amount of months (in this case exactly 4, not 3 or 5 months), the amount of rent received is "rent_2" times (4-0.6300).  The first "if" statement is trying to loop through months 1 to 3, applying the exact same percentage to be deducted. After 3, the percentage differs up till 9 and beyond. This is supposed to be plotted, but only has one value for i (i=1) and ignores i = 2:10

Answer (score 0):

I'm still figuring out what exactly you are trying to do, so I'm going to give you some hints to get your code functional. Once you get it to run without errors, please update your question and we'll try to help you from there.

Your if statement should have logical or in it:

> if a == b | a == c | a == d

Your for loop needs to know what variable it is looping:

> for n = 1:10          % this will evaluate a loop 10 times, once for each value from 1 to 10

When you index an array, your index needs to be a positive integer:

> b = [4, 3, 2, 1];
> a = b(2);            % this will set a to 3 because 3 is the 2nd entry in b
> a = b(1.5);          % this will cause an error since there is no entry at 1.5

Try fixing those and then editing your question and then we can help you more.

UPDATE:

This is a good reference on matlab plotting (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html)

Both your lines should have the same x axis in this case (months) and since you want all of the data in b to be graphed it will not need to be indexed for this purpose.

Comment: My apologies for the ambiguity. So…
1. the loop from 1:10 should begin, with 1:3 first being looped, applying the first equation (b(1,i)=rent_2*(i-0.5040);) So b(1,1)= 1560 * .496. b(1,2)= 1560 * .496. b(1,3)= 1560 * .496.
2. when this loop 1:3 has ended, it should move on to the next elsif statement, since i=4 is reached. Then i=5, and so on. 
3. This should simultaneously build an array (1,10). These are the “y” values in the plot.

Comment: You have written a line of code as both b(1,i)=rent_2*(i-0.5040); and b(1,i)=rent_2(i-0.5040);   Do you mean (i-0.5040) as an index or a value to be multiplied?

Comment: It's meant to be a multiplier: rent_2 * (i-0.5040) (only for i=1:3), since the "0.5040" takes a different percentage, for more months.

Comment: You need a loop around your if statement to increment i. And you need to add the multiplication symbol to your statements to fix them being treated like indices. Try fixing those and then updating your question with new code. Then I can help you graph it.

Comment: for i = 1:10
    if i == 1 | i == 2 | i == 3
        b(1,i)=rent_2 * (i-0.5040);
    elseif i == 4
    b(1,i)=rent_2*(i-0.6300);
    elseif i == 5
    b(1,i)=rent_2*(i-0.7565);
    elseif i == 6
    b(1,i)=rent_2*(i-0.8825);
    elseif i == 7
    b(1,i)=rent_2*(i-1.0085);
    elseif i == 8
    b(1,i)=rent_2*(i-1.1345);
    else
    b(1,i)=rent_2*(i-1.2605);
    end
end

Comment: So I added a loop, looping from 1:10. Then nested the "if" statements so that after looping, the first three are in one part of the "if" statement, then moving on to i=4, applying an equation, then on to i=5, and so on. The plot code at the end just produced a plot where there was only i=1 (or 3, I forget which, will check again tonight), but not the other i's. I would have expected an almost linear line from i=1 to i=10. So far, no luck. The syntax in Matlab is still a bit puzzling.

Comment: I've moved your code updated code into your question. I'll add more hints to my answer

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no reason to mess around with loops and if statements here.

Just as you do this:

```
y = month_count * rent_1;
```

You can have `b` as `rent_2` multiplied by a vector of modifiers. simplified example - if those numbers are calculated by some other equation it would be better to use those rather than typing in by hand, but either way:

```
m = [0.504 0.504 0.504 0.63 0.7565]; % values from your loop/ifs
d = 1:5 - m; %months minus the discount values
rent = rent_2.*d;
```

Comment: This solution is indeed better, thank you. Looked like I was over complicating and overlooking thinking more "matlabby" (in other words, more matrices). Just a small adjustment to above: c = `[1:5] rent= rent_2.*c;`